# Calculating percent of year elapsed/remaining?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to calculate (dynamically) the % of the year that has elapsed, or is remaining.

For example, 25 days of this year have passed, and there's 366 days in the year, so I want to do 25/366, but then obviously the 25 will change everyday.

I thought of a long way to do this using these methods a case/switch expression

```
t = Time.now   #=> 2007-11-19 08:27:03 -0600
t.day          #=> 19
t = Time.now   #=> 2007-11-19 08:27:30 -0600
t.mon          #=> 11
```

For example, something like

```
 if t.mon == 1
    @year = t.day / 366

if  t.mon == 2
    @year = (t.day + 31)/ 366

  if t.mon == 3
    @year = (t.day + 60)/ 366    //60 (or 59) equals number of days in January and Feb etc
```

However, I'm sure there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For day-at-time granularity:

```
require 'date'

today          = Date.today
days_this_year = Date.new( today.year, 12, 31 ).yday
pct_done       = 100.0 * today.yday / days_this_year
#=> 7.1038
```

Alternatively, if you want the granularity of to-the-second accuracy (and no dependency on [`Date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html)):

```
now = Time.now
year_start = Time.new( now.year  , 1, 1 )
year_end   = Time.new( now.year+1, 1, 1 )
pct_done   = 100.0 * ( now - year_start ) / ( year_end - year_start )
#=> 6.8338
```

Comment: one question: do I have to require 'date' in Rails? would you put it in an initializer?

Comment: I don't know; I use [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com), not Rails. I strongly suspect that ActiveSupport already pulls Date in, however. Easy for you to try and see, right?

Comment: Strangely, I didn't get 7.1038. Rather I got this number when I tried your method. 6.830601092896175

Comment: @Michael I've edited it with a more accurate approach that also doesn't need date. Your different answer is because we're in different time zones, and it's just past midnight for me.

Comment: thanks, but weird, why the different results? and, even weirder,  why did I get 6.83 when I tried your first way?

Comment: Different results for Date versus Time because time moves at continuous millisecond intervals, while Date represents exactly midnight on a particular date. I'm only 23 minutes into my current day; using Date put me almost 24 hours ahead of the 'real' value. You got 6.83 because you presumably are still on January 25th, while I am on the 26th.

Comment: Note that this is going to be off by one second in the entire year, as it doesn't include the very last second of the year. You should be subtracting dates exactly a year apart to get the exact result. Though were not building a space ship here so whatever unless we are building a spaceship here in which case it's going to be a lonely drift into the abyss.

Comment: @greg Silly me; fixed. Abyss avoided.

Answer (score 1):

`require 'time'`

`(Time.now.yday.to_f / Time.parse("#{Time.now.year}-12-31").yday.to_f * 100 ).round`