# how to get the number of days elapsed this year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to know if there is a function that shows the number of days elapsed this year until today's date, for example 116 days.

Comment: 2116? Shouldn't be maximum 365 in a leap year?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014872/calculating-percent-of-year-elapsed-remaining

Comment: @Ursus Or 366, as it it usually is.

Comment: you're right @tadman

Comment: You're right, I updated, it's 116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails Active Support adds `#beginning_of_year` method to `Date`:

```
(Date.today - Date.today.beginning_of_year).to_i
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
time = Time.now
thisYear = time.year
dayNum = time.yday
puts "Day number: #{thisYear}.#{dayNum}"
```

Comment: I was going to say [`yday`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-yday) does this, but nobody else but you as noticed.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

Date.today.yday
  #=> 116
```

Comment: This answer is revised from my original one. What you see now was suggested by @steenstag in a since-deleted comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract one date from another:

```
require 'date'
(Date.new(2018, 4, 28) - Date.new(2018, 1, 1)).to_i
#=> 117
```

You will need the `to_i` because otherwise, you would get a `Rational` returned.